# Deleting the contents of common columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with 8 columns. Some rows only differ in certain columns. I would like to delete the contents for the repeated materials
here is what I have

```
|C1|C2|C3|
|A |B |C |
|A |B |D |
```

here is what I want

```
|C1|C2|C3|
|A |B |C |
|  |  |D |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use duplicated:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['A','A'], 'C2':['B','B'], 'C3':['C', 'D']})

df = ~df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated) * df
```

Output:

```
  C1 C2 C3
0  A  B  C
1        D
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mask = np.ravel(np.ones(df.shape, dtype=bool))
flat = np.ravel(df.values)
_, idx = np.unique(df, return_index=True)
mask[idx] = False
mask = mask.reshape(df.shape)
df[mask] = ""
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  C1 C2 C3
0  A  B  C
1        D
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the columns and use pandas' `.duplicated()` to filter the duplicated values and replace with them with empty strings.

```
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[df[col].duplicated(), col] = ''
```

Alternatively you can wrap it in a function and use `.apply()`

```
def replace_duplicates(series):
    is_duplicated = series.duplicated()
    series[is_duplicated] = ''
    return series

df = df.apply(replace_duplicates)
```